# Data validation after migrating from msql to mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb, migration

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I have moved from a mysql db to mongodb. Is there any tools available to run against the two databases to ensure that the data is consistent.

Ive asked Google but ive been coming up empty. The other option i was considering was to write a script and take random samples from the db's and compare the results.

Comment: Just write a script. By the time you invest in learning a tool, if one exists, you'll be done. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is anything for this. The only way that I can see would be to write some script that compares the two data sources. But I do have to point out that if you just merely moved tables to collections, you will run into problems. The data schema that MongoDB likes for optimal performance is in no means going to be similar to what you'd use in a relational database such as MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, another developer has made the conversion and im pretty sure that he has taking performance into account, i was hoping to clear it quickly without having to invest to much time.